# Cross origin, cookies and session

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I couldn't think of any suitable title.

I have two websites under my control. Domain A and domain B. Domain B sets all required CORS header for domain A.

Domain A makes an ajax request to domain B. With this request a session on domain B is created and a cookie with a jsessionid is sent back.

Domain A makes another ajax request with the just received cookie. Some value are set on the session of domain B. This does work as expected.

Then, when I open a new tab and browse to domain B the browser does not send the cookie from the ajax requests. Why is that?

Is the cookie from the ajax requests only temporarily valid and only valid for ajax requests?

**Additional testing**

The above described behavior applies to IE 11. I just did a test in latest Chrome and it does not work at all. No cookie is sent with any subsequent ajax requests.

Example request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function() {
        // do something
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `withCredentials` flag when making your AJAX requests:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.domainb.com/some-resource',
    type: 'GET',
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
});
```

This will force the browser to persist the cookie that has been set during a cross domain request and send it automatically on subsequent calls.

---

UPDATE:

I have setup a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/bhL0vqe3/4/

Comment: As I said, the second request does work. The cookie is set on the second request. I set withCredentials on all ajax requests. I suspect that cookies are only persisted for ajax requests and not for "regular" requests. That is my question.

Comment: Does the server on domain B also set the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` response header to `true`? Could you show the exact request and response payloads that get sent over the wire during this workflow?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the second request would behave different.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce the issue you are describing in your question. You can see this working in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/bhL0vqe3/4/. I have setup a sample mock REST server on this address: `https://www.mocky.io/v2/588b671a300000de1cfa8dfb`. When invoked it will simply return the `Set-Cookie: jsessionid=123;path=/` response header. So in order to test this first open in a new private session this address `https://www.mocky.io` and accept the SSL certificate warning. Then navigate to the jsfiddle address of my sample which makes the AJAX request.

Comment: Then open again the `https://www.mocky.io` address in a new tab and see that the `jsessionid` cookie is sent in the request. Is it possible that your server sets the jsessionid cookie for some specific path when making the AJAX request. For example `Set-Cookie: jsessionid=123;path=/abc`? Then when you open the domain B site on the root level, the cookie is not sent because it is valid only for the `/abc` subpath?

Comment: So I guess, now the question becomes, how does this working setup differs from yours in terms of headers being sent?

Comment: You are right. It does work for me as well. Thanks for the effort. I'll try to find out why I get something else in my case. Maybe it's related to local setup. Domain A is 127.0.0.1 and domain B is localhost in my case.

Comment: I remember that there were some specifics about CORS and localhost, and differences between the browsers. Try playing with your `hosts` file. Simply add 2 rows in it both pointing to 127.0.0.1 and using the `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` records. Then update your client and server application urls so that they use those 2 domains even if everything is hosted locally and you will be able to see this in action and verify whether your setup will work when deployed on the actual environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134205/discussion-between-t3rm1-and-darin-dimitrov).